# cakephp issue in return to referrer url

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to redirect user to the page from which he refereed after login. But not working properly. Sometimes user will redirect to the favicon url. like
`http://www.example/favicon.ico`. Sometimes to a css file.

What I have done is

**AppController.php**

```
$url = Router::url(NULL, true); //complete url
if (!preg_match('/login|logout/i', $url)) {
    $this->Session->write('lastUrl', $url);
}
```

**UsersController.php**

```
if ($this->Session->read('lastUrl')) {
    $this->redirect($this->Session->read('lastUrl'));
    exit;
} else {
    return $this->redirect(Router::url('/', true));
}
```

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: cakephp version is 2.3

Comment: You should just need to do `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());` in your UsersController. I'd also recommend upgrading to CakePHP 2.8!

Comment: I will try this and update you. Thanks @Dakota

Comment: @Dakota : its not working.